# If condition to check wether a specific date is in a leap year

Tags: r

I have a data frame with column `quotedate`, ranging from 2002 to 2022. Now I have to do a calculation for every Date in a leap year. How can I do this?

My plan is to solve it via if condition.

```
If(quotedate in leap year){
   calculation
}
```

Do you have any ideas for the if condition? I can't find a suitable solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way:

```r
library(lubridate)

if(leap_year(quotedate)){do_something}
```